# How can I search and replace a term with brackets in Python without catastrophic backtracking?

Tags: python, regex, latex

I am currently trying to find terms like these (LaTeX definitions)

```
\def\fB{\mathfrak{B}}
```

and then remove the complete term `\def\fB{\mathfrak{B}}` as well as replacing `\fB` by `\mathfrak{B}`.

I came up with the following RegEx to do so:

```
curly = "(?:\{(?:.*)?\})"  # make sure that number of brackets is correct
target = "([^\{]*?"+curly+"*)"
search = r"(\\[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)"
defcommand = re.compile(r"\\def" + search + "\{" + target + "+\}")
```

But when I run this there seems to happen [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) as the following minimal (not) working example shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

text = r"""
\newcommand*{\xindex}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{indexanchor}% make anchor unique
  \def\theindexterm{#1}%
  \edef\doindexentry{\noexpand\index
    {\expandonce\theindexterm|indexanchor{index-\theindexanchor}}}%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\hypertarget{index-\theindexanchor}%
    {\doindexentry}}%
}


\def\fB{\mathfrak{B}}%Für Basis
\def\calS{\mathcal{S}}%Für Subbasis
\def\fT{\mathfrak{T}}%Für Topologie
\def\fU{\mathfrak{U}}%Für Topologie

\newlist{aufgabeenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[aufgabeenum]{label=(\alph*),ref=\textup{\theaufgabe~(\alph*)}}
\crefalias{aufgabeenumi}{aufgabe}

% Commands for local abbreviations
"""


def print_matched_groups(m):
    print("number of groups: %i" % defcommand.groups)
    for i in range(defcommand.groups):
        print("group %i: %s" % (i, m.group(i)))
    print("done with print_matched_groups")

    curly = "(?:\{(?:.*)?\})"
    target = "([^\{]*?"+curly+"*)"
    search = r"(\\[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)"
    defcommand = re.compile(r"\\def"+search+"\{"+target+"+\}")

for m in defcommand.finditer(text):
    print_matched_groups(m)
print("finished")
```

How can I

Comment: Regex is not stateful. It is not the right tool for working with languages with "nested" constructs like brackets. This is why you also don't parse HTML with a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a practical solution. As I know that the nesting will not be very deep, I can use this information to make the regex faster:

```
curly = "(?:\{(?:.*)?\})"  # make sure that number of brackets is correct
target = "([^\{]*?"+curly+"{0, 3})"  # here is the change
search = r"(\\[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)"
defcommand = re.compile(r"\\def" + search + "\{" + target + "+\}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `re` module, you need to use the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which is infinitely superior and offers recursion—which you need to match nested constructs in Python. The syntax will be the same, just with `regex.some_method` instead of `re.the_same_method`.

Here is a recursive regex for curlies that will work in Python with the `regex` module:

```
{(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*}
```

You can admire the effect and play with examples on [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK8zQ1).

Let me know if you have any questions. :)